# Middleware en vuejs no reconoce 'this' ni '$router'

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, middleware

tengo este **middleware** para gestionar los auth de la app:

```
export default (to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to,from,next);
  if (!this.$auth.getToken()) {
    return $router.push({ name: 'login' });
  }

  return next();
};
```

y lo implemento en mi clase de **rutas** de **vue-router**:

```
import auth from "@/Middlewares/Auth"; // <-- Esta es la importacion
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";
import LoginView from "../views/LoginView.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);



const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
    beforeEnter: auth, // <-- Esta es la implementacion
  },

  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: LoginView,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});


export default router;
```

Por otro lado, `this.$auth` es una clase para gestionar los token que solo tiene setters/getters, algo muy simple. La tengo importada **globalmente** en vue de la siguiente manera:

```
Vue.prototype.$auth = new Auth();
```

Y lo que pasa es que en mi fichero del **middleware no reconoce $router ni this.$auth** :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pone que es por `this` pero no entiendo porque esta en **otro contexto** el middleware y no es capaz de leer esas dos variables.